# Probability measure notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, tensors

Has anybody seen probability theory combined with tensor analysis? I think they use a different kind of notation with the standard probability theory. For example in standard probability theory we have $P(x|y)$ which means the probability of $x$ given $y$, and they use the notation $\phi(y)(x)$ which means the same.

Also, the probability measure $P$ is used as an index most of times in the expected value operator, that is $\mathbb{E}_P(X)=\int_{A\in\Omega}(XP)dx$ where $P$ is the probability distribution right?

P.S. forgive me if I am mistaken but I do not have a background in probability theory or measure theory at all.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{E}_P(X)=\int_{A\in\Omega}(XP)dx$ is not right, as there is no "x" there, and "dx" is used to denote the Lebesgue measure. Maybe you mean something like $\mathbb{E}_P(X)=\int_{A\in\Omega}X dP$ or $\mathbb{E}_P(X)=\int_{A\in\Omega}X(\omega )P(d\omega )$ or $\mathbb{E}_P(X)=\int_{A\in\Omega}X(\omega )dP(\omega )$

Comment: @Masacroso thank you for this. I have a problem in understanding this part. Let me explain. by defining the measure $P$ does this mean that we know a pdf over which we will calculate the expected value? But to understand this, maybe it would be helpful if someone could give an example in discrete and continuous rv's about how to use the probability measure.

I have in mind from the probability course that $\mathbb{E}(x)=\int_{A\in \Omega} xf(x)dx$ where $f$ is the pdf of $x$. By defining the measure $P$ isn't this related to the pdf of the rv somehow? I can not understand their relation.

Comment: every random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ induces a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (from the probability measure on $\Omega $), the pushforward measure $P_X$ defined by $P_X(A):=P(X^{-1}(A))$ for any Borel set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. Sometimes this induced measure can be written as $P_X(A)=\int_A f_X(x)dx$ (and we call $f_X$ a density of $X$), some other times as $P_X(A)=\sum_{y\in A}p_X(y)$ when the image of $X$ is countable (and we call $p_X$ the probability mass function of $X$). But in general $P_X$ cannot be written in any of this two ways

Comment: @Masacroso
Ok but explain me how we result from the integral with respect to the measure to the integral with respect to the random variable, namely $$\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x)dx$$ where $f$ is the pdf. I understand that this is standard as notation in most of the textbooks, however it is not  clear how the one turns out to be equivalent to the other.

Comment: this is a long topic, the best thing that you can do is just learn it from some textbook of probability and measure theory. In short: the identity follow just when one of the integrals exists and in this case it hold because it hold for simple measurable functions, and so as the set of simple functions are dense in $L^1$ spaces we are done. The general identity is $\int_\Omega X(\omega )P(d\omega )=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x P_X(dx)$

Comment: I understand that it is a long topic but as I said no book is clear, from those that I have seen. If you have something in mind, any notes ore the section of some book to take a look @Masacroso i would appreciate it if you could give me a link or a title. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I learn mathematics only from books, I dont have any degree or have been taught. You just need some time and practice. Take a look at various introductory textbooks, you have a lot of recommendations here in MSE

Comment: Can you give me one recommendation of such an introductory book? Maybe this one could be more helpful

Comment: first of all, you will need a course in real analysis, and maybe linear algebra also. This is due to the fact that measure theory is an advanced topic in real analysis and its taught in the third of fourth year of a degree in mathematics. Recommendations for introductory books can be searched here, in MSE as I said before, by example you can search something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbook-recommendation%5D+is%3Aquestion+measure+probability) for recommendations of textbooks of measure and probability theory